# Android Tab layout

Tags: android, tabs

I am hiding a tab in Android tab layout. When I start the app again it never loads unless the app is force closed. 
I have tried two approaches

1) Clearing and resetting the tabs and then adding tabs one by one to tabhost.

```
tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
tabHost.clearAllTabs();
tabHost.addTab(//Tab1 related)
tabHost.addTab(//Tab2 related)
tabHost.addTab(//Tab3 related)
```

2) Set the visiblity to Gone for that one particular view.

```
getTabWidget().getChildAt(2).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Both approaches don't seem to help. Any ideas is appreciated.

Comment: Which one is `never loads`? The tabHost or the invisible tab?

Comment: Rephrasing: Once the tab is hidden the tab layout is visible with 2 tabs, but no action can be further performed unless the app is force closed.

Answer (score 0):

Wher did you put the reseting code block? In onCreate or onResume (somewhere else)? If in onCreate, I think you should try to move your method to onResume. Check the events which are received after restarting.

Comment: I have added it in the onresume method.                          "Check the events which are received after restarting." - I have some HTTP requests triggered in the second view which is about to be hidden. Once the tab is hidden, it throws HTTP Status exception. Would that cause any problems?

Comment: It can cause a problem or is a direct successor of an error. Could you paste some bigger snippet to create a better view of the problem? Some stack trace will be nice clue to.